# Can I make double clicking in Visio 2010 Professional open a hyperlink?

Tags: microsoft-visio, hyperlink

How to replace the double click behaviour that leads to adding text in a shape with the intention of having that action opening up a hyperlink to a new page (which describes a subprocess)?

Answer (score 1):

Select the shape, on the **Developer** tab -> **shape design** section, click **Behavior**, select the Double-Click tab and then choose **Go to Page**. You can enable the Developer tab via **File -> Options**.